# Exctracting strings , counting and transposing them as columns in a dataframe

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

Have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns: `tag` and `message`:

```
       tag              |     message
["string1","sttring2"]  |    some text
["string","string3"]    |  another text
["string2"]             | another another text
```

I want to build a dataset for a multi-label classification so I need to extract all the distinct `strings` from `tag` becauuse they are my labels.

**What I need:**

I need to transpose this list of about 40 distinct `strings` in the tag and then insert the count of each relative to the message column.
So the final dataframe should be like this:

```
      tag               |     message           string  string1   string2    string3
["string1","string2"]   |    some text             0      1          1          0        
["string","string3"]    |  another text            1      0          0          1
["string2"]             | another another text     0      0          1          0
```

Do note that `new_df` dataframe must have the 2 originals columns + ~40 new columns because there's about 40 distinct strings in tag column.

How can I do this in Julia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, here are two examples:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(tag=[["string1","sttring2"], ["string","string3"], ["string2"]],
                      message=["some text", "another text", "another another text"])
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ tag                      message
     │ Array…                   String
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ ["string1", "sttring2"]  some text
   2 │ ["string", "string3"]    another text
   3 │ ["string2"]              another another text

julia> [df DataFrame([col => in.(col, df.tag) for col in foldl(union!, df.tag, init=Set{String}())])]
3×7 DataFrame
 Row │ tag                      message               string  string2  string3  string1  sttring2 
     │ Array…                   String                Bool    Bool     Bool     Bool     Bool     
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ ["string1", "sttring2"]  some text              false    false    false     true      true
   2 │ ["string", "string3"]    another text            true    false     true    false     false
   3 │ ["string2"]              another another text   false     true    false    false     false

julia> transform(df, [:tag => ByRow(x -> in(col, x)) => col for col in foldl(union!, df.tag, init=Set{String}())])
3×7 DataFrame
 Row │ tag                      message               string  string2  string3  string1  sttring2 
     │ Array…                   String                Bool    Bool     Bool     Bool     Bool
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ ["string1", "sttring2"]  some text              false    false    false     true      true
   2 │ ["string", "string3"]    another text            true    false     true    false     false
   3 │ ["string2"]              another another text   false     true    false    false     false
```

Comment: one question:  When i read the csv file the first column `tag` is interpreted as `String` and not as `Array`.  Then I am getting this error message: " Cannot `convert` an object of type Char to an object of type String"

Comment: the easiest thing to do is to pre-process it by `df.tag = split.(strip.(df.tag, ['[', ']']))`.